# Netrw: Can't Alt+Tab away & back when composing a command with `q:`

Tags: netrw

When editing a file, I can issue `q:` to open a command palette and compose a Vim command using the full power of Vim's normal mode.  I can also `Alt+Tab` to another window to look for information, then `Alt+Tab` back to Gvim to finish composing the Vim command.

When I'm in a netrw v171 buffer and use `q:` to compose a command, I can't `Alt+Tab` away and back.  I get the following error message, and I also lose the Vim command that I'm composing:

```
 Error detected while processing FocusGained Autocommands
 for "*"..function <SNR>36_LocalBrowseRefresh:
 line   49:
 E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits
```

I never had this problem with older Vim/`netrw` versions, though I admit that I haven't tracked which (I just update everything from Cygwin once in a while).

From the Vim help, I know that `FocusGained` is an event that triggers autocommands, and from the message above, they seem specific to `LocalBrowseRefresh`.  I looked up `SNR`s and understand that they are used to deconflict names between scripts.  I looked for `LocalBrowseRefresh` and `FocusGained` in `netrwPlugin.vim`, but they aren't present.

I have to admit to just rummaging around, and there could be lots of naivity in the way I'm going about it.  ***All I'm seeking is to `Alt+Tab` back and forth from Gvim, even if I started from a `netrw` buffer and am in the midst of composing a command using `q:`.***  Is there a simple way to achieve this or to dig deeper into the cause?

If I can find the cause without taking a hiatus to become an expert in Vimscript, I can try hacking the `netrw` code.  It's not the most reliable approach to a solution, but I've had some success with this for BufExplorer, though that was with tremendous time and effort, and it's my only experience in hacking a plugin.  I also have to re-explore how to implement the hack every time I update Cygwin.

Comment: `fun! s:LocalBrowseRequest()` is actually defined in `autoload/netrw.vim` not in `netrwPlugin.vim`

Comment: Thanks.  I perused that function, as well as instances of `LocalBrowseRefresh`, `FocusGained`, and `netrw_events`, but I can't infer a scheme from them.  Fast browsing seems to crop up everywhere, but I haven't found anything about it.  Ah well.  I appreciate the pointer to the autoload file.

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit: answers belong below in Answers (self-answers are fine and encouraged), not in the Question body.

Comment: Copy that.  I'll add it to romail's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the information we have:

- you are using Netrw,
- you open the command-line window,
- you alt-tab away from Vim,
- you alt-tab back to Vim,
- which throws the following message at you:

  ```
  Error detected while processing FocusGained Autocommands
  for "*"..function <SNR>36_LocalBrowseRefresh:
  line   49:
  E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits
  ```

From there we can already infer, as you did, that something wrong happened when Vim got the focus back. There apparently is at least one autocommand linked to the `FocusGained` event:

```
Error detected while processing FocusGained Autocommands
for "*"
```

that appears to call a `LocalBrowseRefresh()` function:

```
..function <SNR>36_LocalBrowseRefresh
```

where something is done at line 49 that shouldn't be done:

```
line   49:
E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits
```

Now. Finding the offending code is relatively easy. The `36` in `<SNR>36` refers to script number 36 in the output of `:help :scriptnames`. The exact order and path might be different on every system/machine, of course, but it should look something like:

```
21: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim
```

Thankfully, Vim has an internal environment variable that abstracts away the specifics, `$VIMRUNTIME`, so the file where the error happens would be:

```
$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim
```

Here is line 49 of `s:LocalBrowseRefresh()` from that file:

```
exe bufwinnr(ibuf)."wincmd w"
```

The buffer number part of the command is actually irrelevant, here. It essentially does `:wincmd w`, or "move cursor to next window".

Now let's look at `:help e11`, emphasis mine:

> The command-line window is not a normal window. **It is not possible to move to
> another window or edit another buffer**.  All commands that would do this are
> disabled in the command-line window.  Of course it *is* possible to execute
> any command that you entered in the command-line window.  Other text edits are
> discarded when closing the window.

So that line 49 is trying to switch to another window, which is not possible in the command-line window.

**Where to go from there?**

The ideal solution would be to add a check somewhere in the offending function that would prevent that `:wincmd w` if the command-line window is opened.

FWIW, this test has been working fine for me:

```
&buftype ==# "quickfix" || &buftype ==# "nofile"
```

If you don't feel like doing it on your own, you can simply open an issue and wait for the author of Netrw to provide a new version with a fix.

Comment: Thank you, *romainl.*  I didn't follow all of the logic, but most of it.  Your fix worked.  I summarized the resulting changes in the posted question.  I appreciate the time you took to explain the script.

Comment: Okay, we know there's a problem and we know the solution for it. Did anybody care to notify netrw maintainers so the rest of the world could benefit from it?

Comment: That would be on OP, now.

Comment: I created https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/13718 for this

Comment: Thanks!  Do I have to provide a description?  P.S. I also submitted an "issue" to [BufExplorer](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/issues/112) and am wondering whether I should do more to get all the information that I see on *chrisbra's* `netrw` issue.

Comment: The same now problem occurs for line 67 of `LocalBrowseRefresh`, which is `call win_gotoid(curwinid)`. Straddling that line with with the following `if`/`endif` fixes this, too: `if &buftype !=# "quickfix" && &buftype !=# "nofile"` and `endif`.